# function for suffix array python

Tags: python, sorting, suffix-array, suffix

I want to write a function that outputs a suffix array. This is what I have so far:

```
def suffixArray(s):
    sa = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        suffix= sorted([s[i:]])
        sa = [len(s)-len(suffix[i:])
    return list(sa)
```

This outputs an error because I think I'm missing an additional if statement but I'm not really sure how to go about it. And yes, I know that there are probably easier ways to obtain a suffix array but I'm a beginner in python and there are few functions that I can use. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Also here's an example of what I want my input and output to be:
input --> suffixArray('banana')
output--> [5, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2]

Comment: what does each number in output reprsent?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Apparently you're looking to output the indices of a suffix array, but not the actual suffix array? That would look like `['a', 'ana', 'anana', 'banana', 'na', 'nana'].

Answer (score 5):

Apparently you want the index of each suffix after lexicographicly sorting them

```
s = 'banana'
```

```
>>> [t[1] for t in sorted((s[i:],i) for i in range(len(s)))]
[5, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2]
```

or another way:

```
>>> sorted(range(len(s)), key=lambda i: s[i:])
[5, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple suffix array:

```
s = 'banana'
sa = sorted([s[i:] for i in range(len(s))])
```

For an array of suffix indices:

```
s = 'banana'
usd = {i: s[i:] for i in range(len(s))
sai = [x for x, _ in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, generate an array with suffix pairs: the suffix string, and its number:

```
suffixes = [(s[i:], i) for i in range(len(s))]
```

Next, sort this list by the suffix string:

```
suffixes.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Now you can return just the numbers:

```
return [s[1] for s in suffixes]
```

Putting it together:

```
def suffixArray(s):
    suffixes = [(s[i:], i) for i in range(len(s))]
    suffixes.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

    return [s[1] for s in suffixes]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_suffix_array(str_sample):
    lis = list(str_sample)
    suffix_array = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(["".join(trim_elem) for trim_elem in [lis[-len(str_sample)+idx:] for idx in range(len(str_sample))]])}
    return [suffix_array.get(k) for k in sorted(list(suffix_array.keys()))]

print(get_suffix_array('banana'))
```

Result: [5, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2]